# Ingesting 3dimension geospatial data as (WKT) in to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-ingestion, multilinestring

I am trying to ingest a column of WKT with linestring Z in to googlecloud but getting error, and apparently, there is a constraint to WKT in GCP that could not be 3 dimension. Is there any other way to ingest 3 dimension (x, y, z) linestring in to GCP?